# Can't resolve 'tslib' in [path]... for typescript models that reside outside of angular app folder

Tags: angular

For my angular 6 app I use models that reside outside of my angular project folder, because some models are stored in an asp.net core solution where I automatically convert C# classes to typescript classes. I reference these typescript models via export / import barrels in my angular app.

For example, the root folder of my angular app is:

```
C:\Angular_Projects\ng-wfm-sky
```

The path of an exemplary typescript model is:

`C:/VS_Projects/WorkforceMonitorSky/Wfm.Api.OuterFacingModels/Post/WorkorderOfmPost.ts`

which is exported / imported via typesscript barrels using relative paths.

Everything works fine in development mode and the angular app is run without problems using "ng serve".

But I run into errors when building the app using "ng build --prod":

```
ERROR in C:/VS_Projects/WorkforceMonitorSky/Wfm.Api.OuterFacingModels/Post/WorkorderOfmPost.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in 'C:\VS_Projects\WorkforceMonitorSky\Wfm.Api.OuterFacingModels\Post'
```

What I have tried so far:

- explicitly installed tslib into angular project using "npm install --save tslib"

What else can I do to resolve the error and make the angular app build?

Best regards

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259660