# How to avoid "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib'"-error when referencing an external typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

## The question

I have a client/server application, where the client is an angular-app. The server does provide a couple of typescript-definitions for the API it provides. These definitions are loaded from a project-external folder. So far this worked fine, however now I am upgrading from Angular 7 to Angular 8 (and with that also upgrading Typescript from Version 3.1 to 3.5) and when trying to use a non-static enum from the definitions, this now produces this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/path/to/server/definitions'

When the `api.ts`-file is located within the client-dir, then everything works just fine.

**Why is this happening and what I can I do about it?**

## Creating a minimal reproducible example

Here is a quick script to create a minimal example to reproduce:

```sh
mkdir project
cd project
ng new client --minimal=true --skipGit=true --routing=false --style=css
mkdir server
echo 'export enum ApiSample { X = "X" }' > server/api.ts
sed -i 's/"compilerOptions": {/"compilerOptions": {"paths":{"api":["..\/server\/api"]},/' client/tsconfig.json
sed -i -e "1iimport { ApiSample } from 'api';" -e "s/title = 'client';/title = 'client' + ApiSample.X;/" client/src/app/app.component.ts
cd client
npm start
```

Or, alternatively, to create an example manually:

1. Create a new angular project
2. Create somewhere in the filesystem a file "api.ts" with the content `export enum ApiSample { X = "X" }`
3. In the "tsconfig.json" Add `{"paths":{"api":["/path/to/server/api"]}` to the `compilerOptions`
4. Access the `ApiSample.X` from any file of the angular project
5. Run `npm start`

## Findings so far

- The migrator added `"importHelpers": true` in tsconfig.json. That is why it worked before and is not working anymore now. Specifying `"importHelpers": false` in tsconfig.json fixes the issue, but of course this option is there for a reason, so that is no final solution
- Explicitly specifying `"tslib": ["node_modules/tslib"]` fixes the problem. This may be a final solution although it would be interesting to know what is exactly happening and where this is documented.

Comment: I had the very same problem and your solution of explicitly specifying `"tslib": ["node_modules/tslib"]` also fixes my problem. Perhaps it will help someone to say that this has to be specified in tsconfig.json this way:

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...,
    "paths":
    {
      "tslib": ["node_modules/tslib"]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I forget to say that for me this problem began after installing an @angular/cli version  after 8.3.4.

Comment: Any news on the issue? I have the same problem after upgrading from @angular/cli 8.0.0 to 8.3.20.
However, adding the path is NOT working for me!
I have a common path in tsconfig `"common/*": ["../../common/*"]` and all files imported from here crash with "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in '/usr/src/app/common"

Comment: @Kaz: Nope, specifying the path works for me and no new answers where posted. So no news. Is the tslib present in your node_modules folder? If not install it.

Comment: @Kaz I know it is "a little bit" old but I ran into the same problem. `paths` is releative to `baseUrl`. In my case `baseUrl` is set to a specific folder. Therefore I need to use "../node_modules/tslib" as value. Eventually, this helped me even it didn't work in the first place because I missed that it is relative to `baseUrl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Angular 8&9

So for Angular 8 and 9 it seem that adding `"tslib": ["node_modules/tslib"]` to `compilerOptions/paths` in the tsconfig.json does solve the problem.

## Angular 10

In Angular 10 the problem disappeared altogether, no workaround is needed anymore.